# Rails 5 unable to load assets in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets

I am able to precompile assets in **public/asset**s directory of rails application.
But when I start application in production, rails constructing wrong path and not pointing to the precompiled assets.

System environment details are as below.

```
rails -v
Rails 5.0.4

ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]

"sprockets-rails", '2.3.3'
```

and production.rb

```
  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = true

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false
```

and asset.rb

```
# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css *.js.erb *.css.erb)
```

And my index.html.erb looks this way

```
<%=javascript_include_tag "bootstrap.min"%>
<%=stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap.min"%>
```

and the rails trying to fetch assets using below paths,

[image]

and the compiled assets in folders looks as bellow.

[image]

Kindly help me to find out where I am going wrong.
Thanks in advance and any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the digest setting is enabled:

```
config.assets.digest = true
```

Comment: Yes this did trick, I added in production.rb. Thank you for you quick answer.